# Learning OpenGL ES for Android game development

Tags: java, c++, android, opengl-es

What's the best way to run into android game development with OpenGL ES? I tried some tutorials, but all they assume that you are already familiar with OpenGL(using c++). So, if I want to use OpenGL ES I need to learn it with c++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This book is pretty awesome for learning Opengl ES 2.0.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321502795) It does a great job of teaching the ins and outs of opengl es in a platform agnostic POV. From that point the OpenGL/interface examples for the android sdk/ndk should get you where you need to go!

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend looking through the source code for the open-source [ReplicaIsland Game](http://code.google.com/p/replicaisland/)